# How to extract a value from specific bits from a byte array in Python 3?

Tags: python, binary, byte

I have a byte array that is 6 bytes in length (48 bits). Only the first six bits of each byte are relevant. The high two bits do not contain data, so they should be ignored. They should not be included when converting to a number.

I want to extract a specific range of bits from the byte array and convert it to a number, while ignoring the high two bits of each byte.

e.g.
Take the following byte array as an example: b'\x12\x08\x1c\x30\x32\x21'
Bit 47 -> 00010010 00001000 00011100 00110000 00110010 00100001 <- Bit 0

If I want the value for bits 0 through 15. The answer should be 3233(1+32+128+1024+2048)

```
00010010 00001000 00011100 00110000 00110010 00100001  
                               ^^^^ XX^^^^^^ XX^^^^^^
```

If I want the value for bits 6 through 12. it should be 50 (2+16+32)

```
00010010 00001000 00011100 00110000 00110010 00100001
                                  ^ XX^^^^^^ XX
```

I can do this awkwardly in my head, but I'm having issues getting it down in Python. These are the steps that I *think* I should be doing, but I'm not sure if it's the best/easiest way nor how I should be doing it...

1. Convert my byte array into a single string containing it's binary value
2. Change every seventh and eighth character of the binary string (counting from the right side) to another character ("-" for example).
3. Remove any of the "-" characters from the new string. [edited]
4. Extract the bits that I want from the binary string. [edited]
5. Convert that string from a binary to a value.

...so...

1 . How do I take my byte array and convert to a 48 bit binary string?
2 . Is there an easy way to change every seventh and eighth bit to "-" in my binary string?
5 . Convert a string containing a binary value to a number?

...and is my thought process any good on this, or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

I really appreciate any help with this.

[edit] I think I had STEP 3 and 4 in my question in the wrong order... I want to remove the unwanted bits BEFORE I extract my binary digits. Question edited accordingly.[/edit]

Comment: So you want to discard the 2 MSB and combine? So `00110010 00100001` becomes `110010100001`? Are you familiar with the bitwise operators?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with them. My issue is that I need to extract the bits before I can convert them to a number. After the bits are extracted, I lose reference as to what positions they held before being extracted, so I don't know which bits to ignore.

Comment: I should note that I have inserted spaces in my examples above for readability. These spaces won't exist in the actual data used by the script.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding the goal. How do you get `1185` from `00110010 00100001`? If you drop the 2 most significant bits in each number you get `110010 100001`. If you join those you get 3233.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with...

```
def bit_value(data, first_bit, last_bit):
    """ Returns a value based on what bits are set between first_bit and last_bit of a byte array, ignoring bit 7 and 8 of each byte."""

    # Convert bytes to a binary string
    number = int.from_bytes(data, "big")
    bits = f"{number:048b}"

    # Change 7th and 8th bits to "-"
    clean_bits = ""
    for i in range(0,48):
        if i % 8 == 0 or i % 8 == 1:
            clean_bits += "-"
        else:
            clean_bits += bits[i]

    # Strip out the unwanted "-"
    clean_bits = clean_bits.replace("-","")

    # Get the bits we want
    bits_i_want = clean_bits[35-first_bit:36-last_bit]

    # Get the value of the resulting binary string
    value = int(bits_i_want, 2)

    return value
```

Comment: I don't think this solution will provide the correct output: *1.* The slicing order is incorrect, it will produce an empty string, *2.* `The high two bits do not contain data, but they should be counted...`. You clean those bits with `replace` first so they won't be counted and as a result, you will add/include more bits.

Comment: I think I had my STEP 3 and 4 in the wrong order in my question.  I've edited the question to correct my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
bytes6 = bytearray([0b00010010, 0b00001000, 0b00011100, 0b00110000, 0b00110010, 0b00100001])
shift = 30 # Shift first byte this much (6 bits * 5)
result = 0
for b in bytes6:
    result |= (b & 0x3F) << shift
    shift -= 6
print(bin(result))
```

Output: `'0b10010001000011100110000110010100001'`

Comment: I have updated the example in my question to include the byte array that I have to start with. What I need to do is extract a value composed of a portion of bits in that byte array.  

The data I'm using was originally encoded in a six bit character format, so the seventh and eighth bits will never have data and should be ignored, but they exist in my eight bit data stream.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements right, you can try something like this:

**test.py:**

```
def bit_value(data, first_bit, last_bit):
    result = ""

    for i in range(47 - last_bit, 48 - first_bit):
        byte = i // 8
        bit = 7 - (i % 8)

        if bit < 6:
            result += "01"[data[byte] >> bit & 1]

    return int(result, 2)


def main():
    data = b"\x12\x08\x1c\x30\x32\x21"

    test1 = bit_value(data, 0, 15)
    print(f"{test1:#b}, {test1}")

    test2 = bit_value(data, 6, 12)
    print(f"{test2:#b}, {test2}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py 
0b110010100001, 3233
0b10010, 18
```